# How do you remove a parent table row when child "delete" button is clicked in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, rendering

I am rendering table data in React JS and am having trouble getting my table row to go hidden on click of a child "delete" button. My current handler and render functions looks like this:

```
...
changeHandler: function(e) {
 ...
},

deleteHandler: function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.closest("tr").style.visibility = "hidden";
},

render: function() {
    return (
    <div>   
        <div class="container">
          <select onChange={ this.changeHandler.bind(this) }>
            <option></option>
            ...
          </select>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
              ...
              </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {data.map(function(row, j) {
                     return <tr key={j}>
                     <td>{row.text}</td>
                     <td><a href="" onClick={this.deleteHandler.bind(this, j)}>delete</a></td>
                   </tr>                             
                       }
                     )}
            </tbody>
        </table>           
    </div>
  </div>
    );
}
...
```

When I click on the delete anchor, I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

I don't understand why my delete handler isn't being recognized and bound, when the `changeHandler` I'm using is. Could somebody please tell me how to get this event to hit the handler and how to target the parent tr to have it hidden?

Comment: Can we get more of the code or a small chunk => codepen? There is an es6 pen you can fork...try bind(null, j)? Literally shot in the dark w/o example.

Comment: This has everything but the delete handler implemented.

Comment: try [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/ssbdnbw8/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the correction in the typo above, I see that was not the error here. Check out the following fiddle to see it in action. There will be some need of style changes when you hide the row.

https://jsfiddle.net/vgo52rey/

The problem is with the binding of 'this' in the filter function in the fiddle. Abstract that out into another method so you can store the reference to this in a different variable, then you can keep the reference to this.delete or this.deleteHandler.

```
delete: function(e) {
   e.currentTarget.closest("tr").style.visibility = "hidden";
},

renderRows: function() {
  var shouldIRender =(row) => (this.state.filter === row.status || this.state.filter === "");
  var self = this
    return requests.filter(shouldIRender).map(function(row, j) {
                     return <tr key={j}>
                     <td style={tdStyle}>{row.title}</td>
                     <td style={tdStyle}>{row.status}</td>
                     <td style={tdStyle}>{row.created_at}</td>
                     <td style={tdStyle}>{row.updated_at}</td>
                     <td style={tdStyle}><a href="#" onClick={self.delete}>delete</a></td>
                   </tr>                             
                       }
                     )
},
```

in your render method now you can just supply this renderRows method return value:

```
             <tbody>
                 {this.renderRows()}
             </tbody>
```

Comment: I apologize. This was a typo on my part. I have fixed the op. If you would like to see my jsfiddle, [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/ssbdnbw8/12/).

Comment: ok great, I got it working FYI, I'll edit my answer and post the fiddle

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I supplied the main points in code snippets and the code in action can be seen in the fiddle. Is this working for you?

Comment: I'm looking at it now, but I think this basically answers my question.